# How to get version from module

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have 2 repos and I am wanting to get the correct `package.json` version on repo `A`. My code currently returns me the version on repo `B`. The problem is that I am looking at the path `./package.json`. How can I get the correct version?

In repo `A`:

```
@Controller('version')
export class VersionController {
  @Post()
  @HttpCode(200)
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Success',
    type: VersionDto,
  })
  async versionHandler(): Promise<VersionDto> {
    const { version } = require('./package.json');

    try {
      return {
        version,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(err);
    }
  }
```

And in repo `B` app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    
    VersionModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I call the version controller to get the version inside package.json, but unfortunately that gives me the version of repo `A` when instead, it is repo `B`'s version that I want. How can that possible?

Directory Tree:

Repo A:

```
src/
  version/
     version.dto.ts
     version.controller.ts
     version.module.ts
```

Repo b:

```
app.module.ts
src/
```

My attempt at a dynamic Module. This is not working:

```
@Module({})
export class VersionModule {
  static register(options): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: VersionModule,

      controllers: [VersionController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: VersionController,
          useValue: options,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: show us how is your directory tree

Comment: Just updated post @MicaelLevi

Comment: the `package.json` files are at the same level of `src`?

Comment: They are, yes @MicaelLevi

Comment: the app B has app A as its dependency?

Comment: Yes @MicaelLevi

Answer (score 0):

basically you have something like this:

```
B
├── node_modules
│   ├── ...
│   └── A
│       ├── package.json
│       └── code_that_read_package_json.js
└── package.json
```

this is why when you *load* the `package.json` via `require('./package.json')`, you'll always get the `package.json` of the module `A`, due to the relative path (and module resolution rules).

for sure that `require('../../package.json')` will solve that but I don't think this is the right solution.

Instead of reading the entire `package.json` just to grab the `version` field, you could pass this value when registering the `VersionModule` by converting it into a [dyamic module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#dynamic-modules) instead with an [async provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/async-providers).

maybe [this article](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370) will help you.

Comment: Would appreciate an example on how I can pass this value using a dynamic module. I've updated my post with how I am attempting to do a dynamic module, but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the full reasoning is, but you could probably end up doing something like

```js
const packageJSON = (await readFile(join(process.cwd(), 'package.json'))).toString();
const version = JSON.pasre(packageJSON).version;
```

Where `readFile` is `promises.readFile` from `fs` and `join` is from `path`. Should be all built in functionalities and it should read the proper package.json depending on where the code is ran from. Otherwise you can try `require.resolve(package.json)` to be a bit more dynamic and leave the heavy lifting logic to `require`. Just keep in mind how `require`ing the `package.json` can modify the outdir due to what has to be ready by typescript.